# Dynamically change Linq Select

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

in this piece of code:

```
        protected async Task<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>> GetListAsync(string tableName, string key, string value, string orderBy = "Id")
    {
        var query = $"SELECT {value},{key} FROM {tableName} ORDER BY {orderBy}";
        var result = await QueryAsync<dynamic>(query);
        return result.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.Id, x.RoleName));
    }
```

I'm trying to Create a dynamic generic method to handle getting list of any of my tables
the problem is I cannot recognize how to send key and value overloads instead of x.Id, x.RoleName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using column aliases:

```
protected async Task<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>> GetListAsync(string tableName, string key, string value, string orderBy = "Id")
{
    var query = $"SELECT [{key}] as [KEY] , [{value}] as [VALUE] FROM [{tableName}] ORDER BY [{orderBy}]";
    var result = await QueryAsync<dynamic>(query);
    return result.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.KEY, x.VALUE));
}
```

Update: I added square brackets everywhere to make it work. Not only is KEY a reserved word, the column names that are passed in might also be keywords, or they could contain spaces/special characters. This will make it work for almost any case (as long as you don't have square brackets *inside* column names).

Comment: @Siolishe This should have worked. What error do you get?

Comment: Please give more detail what happens, just stating "it doesn't work" is never enough.

Comment: changing SELECT {key} as KEY to SELECT {key} as [KEY] solve the problem :)

Comment: Ah great, and in hindsight it is so obvious because KEY is a reserved word in SQL. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to retrieve properties by name from **dynamic**, especially if it is implementing **IDynamicMetaObjectProvider**

So, hack is to use serialization to JSON, and access it's properies by name then.

Return statement should look like this (used [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) here):

```
return result.Select(x => {
    var jo = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(d);

    return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(jo[key], jo[value]);
});
```